# R function using previous rows in same and different columns?

Tags: r

Starting with the iris data set:

I want to create a new column B, where the value for row 1 is the value of Sepal.Length and the values for rows 2:n = B from the previous row +(Sepal.length of the current row - Sepal.length of the previous row).
so row B1 = 5.1, B2=5.1+(4.9-5.1 ...

Thanks!

edit: The above described patter is only partial: the formula should only apply when (Sepal.length of the current row - Sepal.length of the previous row).  Based on The Governor's answer, the code below works for the edited question:

```
MyDataSet<-data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3)) 
B <- rep(NA,(nrow(MyDataSet))) 
B[1] <- MyDataSet$time[1] 

for (i in 2:nrow(MyDataSet)) { 
if (0<MyDataSet$time[i]-MyDataSet$time[i-1])
{B[i] <- B[i-1]+(MyDataSet$time[i]-MyDataSet$time[i-1]) }  
 else {B[i]<-B[i-1]+MyDataSet$time[i]} 
} 

MyDataSet$B <- B
```

Comment: `value for row 1 is the value of Sepal.Length and the values for rows 2:n = B from the previous row` there is no previous row before row 1.  What is `n`?

Comment: row 1 would simply be Sepal.length row 1.  The formula would start at row 2.

Comment: Do you need `head(iris) %>% mutate(new = Sepal.Length + c(diff(Sepal.Length), 0))`

Comment: BTW, `5.1 + (4.9 - 5.1) -> 4.9`

Comment: Call the previous row `PR` and the current row `CR`. You want `PR + CR - PR = CR`...?

Comment: @Gregor: For two columns A and B: I want CRB=PRB+CRA-PRA.  But as a column in the dataset.

Comment: Yes, but since you start with `B[1] = A[1]`, then, as akrun points out and your own example shows, `B[2] = 5.1 + 4.9 - 5.1 = 4.9 = A[2]`. So `B[2] = A[2]`. Then `B[3] = B[2] + A[3] - A[2]`, which  since `B[2] = A[2]` means `B[3] = A[3]`. etc. So `B = A`. `iris$B = iris$Sepal.Length` is what is described in your question. If this is not correct, please fill out the "..." in your question until the difference is obvious.

Comment: I have the wrong pattern.  The actual data I am working with a time stamp that periodically restarts at 0.  So it would be  A<-c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)  I need B to be the continuous time, so b<-c(0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6).  I though that adding the difference of A and a previous column would work, but the 0 throws it off. So I need rows in which A=0 to be B=B(previous row)+A(current row), while all the others are B=B(previous row)+A(current row)-A(previous row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
data(iris)

B <- rep(NA, (nrow(iris)))
B[1] <- iris$Sepal.Length[1]
for ( i in 2:nrow(iris)){
  B[i] <- B[i-1]+(iris$Sepal.Length[i]-iris$Sepal.Length[i-1])  
}
```

@Lina Bird you're right I forgot to add

```
iris$B <- B
```

Note that there may be a more elegant/efficient way to do this using the package dplyr and the function mutate.

Comment: `all(B == iris$Sepal.Length)` returns true. So this is a long way to write `iris$newcol = iris$Sepal.Length`

Comment: Based on The Governor's answer, the code below works for the edited question:             ` MyDataSet<-data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3)) B <- rep(NA, (nrow(MyDataSet))) B[1] <- MyDataSet$time[1] for (i in 2:nrow(MyDataSet)) { if (0<MyDataSet$time[i]-MyDataSet$time[i-1]) {B[i] <- B[i-1]+(MyDataSet$time[i]-MyDataSet$time[i-1]) } else {B[i]<-B[i-1]+MyDataSet$time[i] } } MyDataSet$B <- B`